# JavaScript: save entity, can it be written better?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a method that saves in the user database. Because my database has relationships, I need user_id from UserEntity in the userAuth and userSalary tables so the `user` variable have to be first. But I want to return the whole User model with relations in response.

Can you write this method more elegantly? like e.g Promise.all or anything functions in ES6+?

```
async createUser(userRegisterDto: UserRegisterDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const user = this.userRepository.create({ ...userRegisterDto });
    await this.userRepository.save(user);

    const userAuth = this.userAuthRepository.create({
        ...userRegisterDto,
        user,
    });
    await this.userAuthRepository.save(userAuth);

    const userSalary = this.userSalaryRepository.create({
        ...userRegisterDto,
        user,
    });
    await this.userSalaryRepository.save(userSalary);

    return user;
}
```

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. It's a *tiny* bit WET, but making it DRY would come at a significant expense of readability IMO. Though, your current code runs all `.save`s in *serial* - is that desirable, or just coincidence? It could be made to use `Promise.all` instead, if that's the logic you want, and if parallel processing doesn't cause any problems

Answer (score 1):

Lines 5-8 are almost identical to lines 10-13, so you can factor those out to a separate function:

```
async function saveUserToRepo(repo, userRegisterDto: UserRegisterDto, user) : Promise {
    const newItem = repo.create({
        ...userRegisterDto,
        user,
    });
    await repo.save(newItem );
}

async createUser(userRegisterDto: UserRegisterDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const user = this.userRepository.create({ ...userRegisterDto });
    await this.userRepository.save(user);

    await saveUserToRepo(this.userAuthRepository, userRegisterDto, user);
    await saveUserToRepo(this.userSalaryRepository, userRegisterDto, user);

    return user;
}
```

And if it's ok to run both of those middle saves in parallel without causing any issues (you'd need to be the judge of that), you can use `Promise.all` to track them in parallel:

```
async createUser(userRegisterDto: UserRegisterDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const user = this.userRepository.create({ ...userRegisterDto });
    await this.userRepository.save(user);

    await Promise.all([
        saveUserToRepo(this.userAuthRepository, userRegisterDto, user),
        saveUserToRepo(this.userSalaryRepository, userRegisterDto, user),
    ]);    

    return user;
}
```